# Random picking in dictionary

Tags: python

So i have a dictionary with:

```
dict = {1:'hi', 2:'bye', 3:'who', 4:'which', 5:'where'}
```

and I'm trying to **randomly extract 3 words** from the dictionary and **append into a list.**

I tried:

```
import random
lst = []
pick = random.choice(lst.keys())
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: `pick = random.sample(list(dict.keys()), 3)`

Comment: @turtle is it possible to just extract the word portion instead of the keys?

Comment: ```result = random.sample([v for v in dict.values()], number_of_words)```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
dict = {1:'hi', 2:'bye', 3:'who', 4:'which', 5:'where'}
random.choice(list(dict .keys()))

nr,text= random.choice(list(dict .items()))
```

try this?

Comment: @Belgiumclub thanks, but what if i want to randomly extract 3 words instead of 1?

Comment: @Maxxx loop over the random choice and keep it in a list till you have 3 random answers if they need to be unique then filter it hope this helps :)

Comment: This is not correct: He can get double values in his result. He wrote "extract" which implies you can not make the same choice again. With your code it it possible to get ```['hi','hi','hi']``` as a result.